# Create install anywhere launcher from executable jar

Tags: java, jar, spring-boot, installanywhere

I have a jar file that is being created by Spring Boot. Application runs smoothly when run by command `java -jar`. I want to create an install anywhere launcher with this jar file.

What I have tried is to send the Spring Boot main class (`PropertiesLauncher`). The issue is that calling it like this won't load the nested jars inside my executable jar and also the `loader.path` doesn't seems to work.

Is there a way to call the executable jar like `java -jar` from the install anywhere launcher?

I was thinking that another option was to create an install anywhere launcher for a script file and inside have the `java -jar` call. So another question will be:
How do I create an install anywhere launcher for a script file?

Answer (score 0):

**'execute command'** step will do the trick:

Use this command line:

```
java -jar <path.to.jar.file>
```

Use EXECUTE_STDOUT, EXECUTE_STDERR and EXECUTE_EXITCODE built-in variables to catch errors and parse the jar's execution result.

**Important notes:**

You'll have to make sure your jar includes all of the dependencies (or at least set the classpath in the command line);

To include the dependencies within your jar using **eclipse** you can:

1. Export your project as a 'runnable jar file' and select the
   'Extract/Package required libraries into generated JAR' option/s
2. Use Maven to build the project with dependencies; the
   maven-assembly-plugin is required.

The **'execute command'** will work for **batch/cmd/shell** scripts as well, but you'll have to make sure the scripts are extracted to a local folder such as %TEMP% or /tmp before you can use them.

Goodluck